# Bootstrap does not working on subroutes on node js app

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, routes

server : express
templating : ejs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1siLQ.png)
above is the routes of app
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1n4c.png)
above is the render of app

please need help !!

bootstrap works fine for 
/
/auth
/auth/
but does not works for 
/auth/login
/auth/signup

Comment: Open the dev tools and check the network tab. What do you see for the css files?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.